# How do perform grid search for xgboost in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost, grid-search

I have some classification problem in which I want to use xgboost.
I have the following:

```
alg = xgb.XGBClassifier(objective='binary:logistic')
```

And I am testing it log loss with:

```
cross_validation.cross_val_scoree(alg, train_cluster_x, train_cluster_y, cv=5, scoring='log_loss')
```

I am trying to perform grid search the following way:

```
clf = GridSearchCV(alg,{'max_depth': [2,4,6],
                        'n_estimators': [50,100,200]}, 
                        verbose=1, 
                        error_score='log_loss')

clf.fit(train_cluster_x,train_cluster_y)
clf.best_score_, clf.best_params_
```

But I get different results.
Is the grid search calculating the log loss now, as the cross validation?

Comment: When you say you get different results, do you mean that each time you re-run the script you get a different best score and best params? If so, that's pretty common. Each time you re-run, your data is being split differently, so the specifics of the best model will often be slightly different. It would help if you could give examples of the output you receive, letting us know what you expect and what you see instead.

Answer (score 3):

The difference occurs in the Grid Search settings. The error_score means the value when raising error. You should specify the scoring parameter to 'neg_log_loss'.

```
clf = GridSearchCV(alg,{'max_depth': [2,4,6],
                    'n_estimators': [50,100,200]}, 
                    verbose=1, 
                    scoring='neg_log_loss')

clf.fit(train_cluster_x,train_cluster_y)
clf.best_score_, clf.best_params_
```